# Why there are several duplicated entries when I set the cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jquery-cookie, js-cookie

I use the library [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). Previously, I used `jquery.cookie`.
I have some issue with duplicating cookie entries.
Some time, when i call

```
Cookies.set('my-cookie-name', 'value', {'path': '/'});
```

I am sure that I call this method only one place in my code, but in result I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Name               Value     Domain              Path
---------------------------------------------------------------
my-cookie-name     1         mydomain.com        /foo/bar/
my-cookie-name     value     mydomain.com        /
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does not happen every time.
This problem occurs rarely, so it is difficult to catch. At this moment i remove cookie before set new value and do not catch the problem again. But i think it is wrong usage.

Cookie with name `'my-cookie-name'` sets in only one place of code.
This issue i catch on my dev machine, so it can't be a old cookie.

I use it for toggle some state. i mean like this:

```
var state = 'on';
$elem.on('click', function(e){
    state = state === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
    Cookies.set('my-cookie-name', state, {path: '/'});
});
```

May be it's wrong usage? And i need to remove old cookie before set new value?

Browser: Chrome v45

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/98)

Answer (score 2):

A cookie is defined by its domain, path and secure attributes, you need to take extra care to avoid duplicates.

But why might this be happening? It is hard to tell, but here is my theory:

1. Even though you call it once, the user could already have a cookie locally. Changing the code does not delete a cookie that was persisted earlier.
2. You might be passing an Object Literal reference in the attributes argument, then another code change the Object eventually and the cookie set operation is run afterwards with a different Path.
3. The other cookie is being set in the server with different attributes, so when you try to set in the client, it duplicates.
4. Some code is changing the behavior of `Cookies` methods at runtime and then when you call `Cookies.set()` it is duplicating the cookie.

Besides those options I can't think of another reason for this happening.

I recommend you follow [this guide](http://sscce.org/), it tells you how to reduce your code in order to narrow down the problem.

We have plans to [write some docs about duplicated cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/37#issuecomment-113964814). In the same link you can find related topics that might help you to tackle down the problem.

I hope it helps.